# Не запускается скрипт python в docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Что делаю не правильно?

Запускаю :
`docker compose up --build`

контейнеры запущены

далее пытаюсь запустить скрипт: `docker-compose exec auth python auth.py` и ничего не происходит, как-будто зависает...

Структура моего проекта:

```
my_project
  auth
    auth.py
    requirements.txt
    Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yaml
```

Сейчас мой Dockerfile такой:

```
FROM python:3.11.5-slim

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 6100

# copy source code into working directory
COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "-m", "auth.py" ]
```

А docker-compose.yaml такой:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  auth:
    build: ./auth
    container_name: auth
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=SECRET_KEY
      - PORT=6100
      - DB_USERNAME=admin
      - DB_PASSWORD=root
      - DB_HOST=db_auth
      - DB_PORT=6101
      - DB_NAME=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db_auth
    networks:
      - internal_net

  db_auth:
    container_name: db_auth
    ports:
      - "6101:6101"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
    image: postgres:16.1-alpine
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "port=6101"
    volumes:
      - db_auth_vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - internal_net

volumes:
  db_auth_vol: {}

networks:
  internal_net:
    driver: bridge
```